# run docker exec on possibly stopped container, so that it would execute without error

Tags: docker

I would like to run `docker exec` on some, possibly stopped docker container.

By possibly I mean that it could be running just fine but in some cases, namely server reboot and so on, container that I want run `docker exec` would be stopped.

Is there any good way to make sure that docker exec would execute without error in both cases (container running, container stopped). And in case of stopped wouldn't return:

`Error response from daemon: Container is not running`

Answer (score 1):

From `docker exec --help`

you can find, among other things

`Run a command in a running container`

I do not know what you want to do with a stopped container?

Maybe try to restart it?

You know you can start a container with a restart policy to always

see the doc

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

Extract

`Always restart the container regardless of the exit status. When you specify always, the Docker daemon will try to restart the container indefinitely. The container will also always start on daemon startup, regardless of the current state of the container.`

Answer (score 1):

You can't run `docker exec` against a stopped container. From `docker help exec`:

> $ docker help exec
>
> Usage:  docker exec [OPTIONS] CONTAINER COMMAND [ARG...]
>
> Run a command in a **running container**

So if your target container has been stopped by some reason, you need to start it by `docker start <your_container>` before you can do `docker exec ....`

BTW, `docker run` command has an option called `--restart` to let you to specify a restart policy for the container, you can find more details on [docker run --restart docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies---restart). There're 4 policies available:

- **no**: Do not automatically restart the container when it exits. This is the default.
- **on-failure[:max-retries]**: Restart only if the container exits with a non-zero exit status. Optionally, limit the number of restart retries the Docker daemon attempts.
- **always**: Always restart the container regardless of the exit status. When you specify always, the Docker daemon will try to restart the container indefinitely. The container will also always start on daemon startup, regardless of the current state of the container.
- **unless-stopped**: Always restart the container regardless of the exit status, but do not start it on daemon startup if the container has been put to a stopped state before.

By default it's `no`, you could choose another one based on your requirement. For example if you choose `non-stopped`, your container will got restarted automatically when docker daemon is ready after your server reboot.